# Plugin Vertical Photo Placer on QGIS - How to use

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

Is someone already used the plugin "Vertical Photo Placer" on QGIS ?

Apparently, this plugin is able to use data contained in the EXIF (coordinates, altitudes, etc.) and the dimensions of a drone picture, to process automatic georeferencing on WGS84.

I tried it and the result I get, using the "Quick view" or "simple correction" with DEM, is not correct. The picture is well located, but its size is different from the basemap.

Here is a picture of the result :

[image: Result]

You can see that the red roof of the building hasn't the same size.

Do you think there is a way to make it work properly, or is this the best I can get with an automatic calculation?

Link to the plugin's GitHub page:[Link to plugin](https://github.com/verticalphotoplacer/VerticalPhotoPlacer/issues)

Link to the tutorial: [Link to tutorial](https://verticalphotoplacer.github.io/VerticalPhotoPlacer/)

Comment: Hi, this is probably due to the altitude problem. The plugin uses barometer altitude to estimate size of the image on map. But barometer altitude is referenced to home point altitude. You may try Adjacent photo matching (requires at least two photos) or Home point correction (if you know where the home point is) instead.

Comment: This task really requires some complex math and more information than VPP has access to like the CMOS sensor size and an accurate elevation. VPP can get you to the basic area and a decent rotation but some georeferencing will be required.